# Mixing grid auto layout with a fixed row-column position

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following HTML with a CSS grid

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div class="main-item">Main</div>
</div>
```

```css
#grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
    text-align: center;
}

#grid > * {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 20px;
}

#grid > .main-item {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: 3 / 5;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

The important part is `.main-item` has a fixed *position* in the grid.

I now add 25 *cells* to the grid.

```js
const grid = document.querySelector("#grid");

for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    const item = document.createElement("div");
    item.innerText = i.toString();
    grid.append(item);
}
```

The problem is that I want these elements to ignore the position of the `.main-item` (treat it as if it wasn't there). However the CSS currently corrects for this and flows the elements around `.main-item`. I want the secondary behaviour below:

[image]

I can correct by setting `style.gridRow` and `style.gridColumn` in the JavaScript

```js
item.style.gridRow = (Math.floor(i / 5) + 1).toString();
item.style.gridColumn = ((i % 5) + 1).toString();
```

Is there a way to do this without setting every other element in JS? Is there a CSS to prevent fixed element affecting the flow correction?

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/kaleidawave/pen/eYPqQWO)

Comment: What exactly would you like to achieve - to position the numbers like on the first picture or you don't want to have the last 3 cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the grid a relative position and position that specific grid item absolutely.

```js
const grid = document.querySelector("#grid");
for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    const item = document.createElement("div");
    item.innerText = i;
    grid.append(item);
}
```

```css
#grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

#grid > * {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 20px;
}

#grid > .main-item {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: 3 / 5;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div class="main-item">Main</div>
</div>
```